# Is high HC reading a legitimate reason to refuse catalytic converter warranty claim?

Tags: honda, catalytic-converter, warranty

**Original problem**

- P0420 fault code
- high CO readings (1st fast-idle test, UK MOT emissions report)

The vehicle is a 2006 Honda with a K20-series petrol engine, and the catalytic converter was a non-OEM replacement (original had been stolen).

After replacing the catalytic converter, the fault code didn't come back which, to me, confirms that the catalytic converter was the cause of the problem.

I tried to return the catalytic converter for warranty replacement, but the warranty claim was rejected as apparently in the emissions report that I provided as part of the warranty claim, the HC readings are too high and suggest 'over fuelling'. (HC reading is within the allowable UK MOT standard threshold of 200ppmvol)

| Fast idle test |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Speed | rpm | 2987 |
| CO | %vol | 0.6 |
| HC | ppmvol | 93 |
| Lambda |  | 1.009 |

Is this a high HC reading, and if so, is that a legitimate reason for manufacturers to refuse a refund/warranty claim?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the cat manufacturer's warranty?

Comment: @MTA All I can find is a small box on their homepage (https://ibb.co/kq3HWRh) which isn't very informative unfortunately.

Comment: Why is your HC reading high?  You realize, I hope, that an excess HC reading can literally burn the cat from the inside out.   So I would say yes, a misconfigured engine can indeed destroy the cat and void any warranty it might have had.  But overall you've provided way too little information beyond this.

Comment: According to [this source](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/676700/in-service-exhaust-emission-standards-for-road-vehicles-19th-edition.pdf), CO should be less than 0.2% and HC less than 200ppm at fast idle. I'm not seeing as how you are out of spec on the HC? Not even what I'd call a "high normal". To my understanding, there are two separate portions of the cat; one handles CO and the other handles HC (this being a "two-way cat"). Even if the HC portions was burned out, it should still handle CO, which it isn't.

Comment: @ec2011 Your question can't be answered without referring to the manufacturer's warranty. What are the terms and conditions? What are the exclusions? They claim to have a "no quibble" warranty. As a paying customer, you are entitled to see that warranty. You can't find it online so can you (eek!) call them and ask them to email it to you? If not, all that's left is to accept their decision.

Comment: @MTA I'll ask the retailer about the warranty, meanwhile I've found this which doesn't really give that much more detail (https://ibb.co/Smv4VcD). Technically my contract is with the retailer rather than the manufacturer, though the retailer just forwarded me the letter as they received it from the manufacturer.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks for your response. I'm not sure if that HC reading is high to begin with. The catalytic converter manufacturer claims it is, but it's well within the allowable threshold as per the standards document that Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 linked to.
If that is high - only other thing I'm aware of is there was a code for faulty knock sensor that started after the P0420 code. But coming back to the catalytic converter, my mechanic just told me "it's either bad o2 sensor or bad catalytic converter". Since CO readings were high and fault code identifies catalytic converter I had that replaced first.